# Convert the columns in each element of a list to strings

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have a list of 3 elements `x`, `y` and `z`. The cols in each of these lists are of type `double`. Is there a quick way to convert the all the cols to strings?

```
dput(mylist)
list(structure(list(Age = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Year = c(10L, 
11L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(Age = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Year = c(12L, 
14L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(Age = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Year = c(12L, 
14L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)))
```

I've tried various ways with `lapply` but just can't get it right.

Comment: Try `lapply(mylist, function(i) {i[] <- lapply(i, as.character); i})`

Comment: And, just to give a second alternative: `lapply(mylist, lapply, as.character) |> lapply(data.frame)`.

Comment: @Sotos first answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With double `lapply`,

```
lapply(mylist, function(i) {i[] <- lapply(i, as.character); i})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try `rapply`

```
res <- rapply(
  mylist,
  as.character,
  how = "replace"
)
```

and you will see

```
> res
[[1]]
  Age Year
1   1   10
2   1   11
3   2   10
4   3   11
5   4   10
6   5   12

[[2]]
  Age Year
1   1   12
2   1   14
3   2   10
4   3   11
5   4    5
6   5   12

[[3]]
  Age Year
1   1   12
2   1   14
3   2   10
4   3   11
5   4    5
6   5   12

> str(res)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':       6 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Age : chr [1:6] "1" "1" "2" "3" ...
  ..$ Year: chr [1:6] "10" "11" "10" "11" ...
 $ :'data.frame':       6 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Age : chr [1:6] "1" "1" "2" "3" ...
  ..$ Year: chr [1:6] "12" "14" "10" "11" ...
 $ :'data.frame':       6 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Age : chr [1:6] "1" "1" "2" "3" ...
  ..$ Year: chr [1:6] "12" "14" "10" "11" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `purrr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mylist <- map(mylist, ~.x %>% mutate(across(.fns = as.character))) 
str(mylist)

#List of 3
# $ :'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ Age : chr [1:6] "1" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  ..$ Year: chr [1:6] "10" "11" "10" "11" ...
# $ :'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ Age : chr [1:6] "1" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  ..$ Year: chr [1:6] "12" "14" "10" "11" ...
# $ :'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ Age : chr [1:6] "1" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  ..$ Year: chr [1:6] "12" "14" "10" "11" ...
```

Or a shorter version using only `purrr` (suggested by @Konrad Rudolph )

```
map(mylist, map_dfr, as.character)
```

Comment: Shorter ‘purrr’: `purrr::map(x, purrr::map_dfc, as.character)`